# How to get rid of NFC icon?

Tags: nfc, notification-icons, sony-xperia-z5

After a forced OS reinstall by a repair shop a Sony Xperia Z5 Compact started to show a NFC icon in a status bar. 
How to get rid of it? It does not give any information as it is always on, so it is just annoying.

- The icon is not an option in Display / System Icons
- Any other Xperia (even with same OS 5.1.1) does not have it, including this one before the service
- in `build.prop` it is turned off by `ro.nfc.icon.enable=false`
- NFC should be on, I use it, but the icon should be hidden like it was, because there is no info in showing it and clutter the status bar

Stock (unrooted) Sony Xperia Z5 Compact Android 5.1.1

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can't you just go into settings and turn off NFC?

Comment: @acejavelin Please read the Q again: *NFC should be on, I use it, but the icon should be hidden* :)